# drove or was driving?

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

Is it true that if I say "Joe got a ticket because he drove too fast", this means that Joe drove too fast as a habit and instead I should say "Joe got a ticket because he was driving too fast"?

Is it true that "Joe drove too fast last night" and "Joe was driving too fast last night" can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Neither sentence describes (or even implies) a habit. For a *habit* it would need to be something like this: *There's something you need to know about Joe. He drives too fast.* Or *He has been driving too fast.* Both sentences in your question merely say that he *happened* to be driving too fast the one time he got a ticket.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Does it make a difference if I change the sentence into: " He was stopped because he drove too fast"?

Comment: Not in terms of a described habit, no.

Comment: the "habit" explanation was given to me by a native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple past can be used to describe a single event in the past. This makes the meanings of "...because he drove" and "...because he was driving" very similar. There is a slight difference in viewpoint (whether the fast driving was a single event or a continuous process) but this is minor.  I would tend to use the past continuous "...was driving..." because the process of driving fast took longer than getting a ticket, and he was stopped while the process was ongoing. Compare

> John was arrested because he shot Sally.

(not "was shooting" we are talking about a single event not a process)

Similarly in the main clause "John was driving" and "John drove" indicates we are thinking about the event slightly differently:

> John drove to the shops
>
> John arrived early at the party because he drove.

It was an event

> John was driving to the shops (when his tyre burst).

It was an ongoing process that was stopped by a short event.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give an example with "because he drove" as a single event?

Comment: I've added such an example.

Comment: Sorry James, I don't understand this sentence. Does it mean he arrived early, because he went by car? Why not use the past perfect ? The driving happened before the arrival.

Comment: You could have used a past perfect, but the past perfect is rarely essential.